# How to implement ad blocker on a custom browser?

Tags: ios, adblock

I try to find some way to remove ad elements from website on my custom browser. I tried to use **Content Blocker** but it seems to only work for Safari. How can I implement this feature?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For example, I create a Content Blocker Extension target and add some rules to blockerList.json. How can I make my own browser(normal WKWebView) apply the rules?